# List that shows which element has the largest value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to make a function that will take elements and values input by the user, and list whichever element has the highest value. For example,

```
['H', 14.5, 'Be', 2.5, 'C', 50.5, 'O', 22.5 'Mg', 4.0, 'Si', 6.0]
```

the correct answer is 'C'. I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. I don't have any code yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You can zip the list with itself to get alternating tuples. If you put the number first, you can just use `max()` to get the largest. This assumes there are not ties:

```
l = ['H', 14.5, 'Be', 2.5, 'C', 50.5, 'O', 22.5, 'Mg', 4.0, 'Si', 6.0]
num, symbol = max(zip(l[1::2], l[::2]))
# (50.5, 'C')
```

This works because tuples are compared in order and zipping alternating values gives a collection of tuples like:

```
list(zip(l[1::2], l[::2]))
# [(14.5, 'H'), (2.5, 'Be'), (50.5, 'C'), (22.5, 'O'), (4.0, 'Mg'), (6.0, 'Si')]
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you try to find a maximum element in a list that contains both strings (e.g., 'C') as keys and numbers (e.g., '50.5') as values. For this purpose, a dictionary is more convenient:

```
dictionary = {'H': 14.5, 'Be': 2.5, 'C': 50.5, 'O': 22.5, 'Mg': 4.0, 'Si': 6.0}
max_key = max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
print(max_key)
# 'C'
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
li=['H', 14.5, 'Be', 2.5, 'C', 50.5, 'O', 22.5, 'Mg', 4.0, 'Si', 6.0]
```

Create tuples and then take `max` of those tuples:

```
>>> max(((li[i],li[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(li),2)), key=lambda t: t[1])
('C', 50.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each numerical value is positive:

```
lst = ['H', 14.5, 'Be', 2.5, 'C', 50.5, 'O', 22.5, 'Mg', 4.0, 'Si', 6.0]

index, _ = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda p: p[1] if isinstance(p[1], float) else 0)
el = lst[index-1]
print(el)
```

otherwise first filter by type and then get the index of the maximal value

```
_, index = max(((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(lst) if isinstance(v, float)))
el = lst[index-1]
print(el)
```